# What does coordinate projection of a scheme mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the following statement (paraphrased) in the paper [The fluctuations in the number of points of smooth plane curves over finite fields](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X1000168X) by A. Bucur, C. David, et al.

> Suppose I have a reduced subscheme $V$ of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^2$. If it has dimension at least $1$, then the projection in one of the coordinates, say $x_1$, will be a $1$-dimensional subscheme of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^1$. Therefore no nonzero polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_1]$ can vanish on $V$, since that would mean that it vanishes on $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^1$.

What exactly is this projection map? Is it just composition of the map $V \rightarrow \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{F}_q}^2$ with the map of schemes associated to the inclusion of rings $\mathbb{F}_q[x_1] \hookrightarrow \mathbb{F}_q[x_1,x_2]$.

Why is the image of this map a $1$-dimensional subscheme? And why does a nonzero polynomial in $x_1$ not vanish on it?

Comment: In the classical sense, I think I understand what's happening. But I want to understand it rigorously in the language of schemes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the projection is the scheme map corresponding to the inclusion of rings $\Bbb F_q[x_1]\hookrightarrow \Bbb F_q[x_1,x_2]$.

As for why the projection on at least one of the coordinates must be 1-dimensional, suppose the projection on both coordinates was zero-dimensional. Then as $V\subset pr_1^{-1}(pr_1(V))\times pr_2^{-1}(pr_2(V))$, our variety would be dimension zero, contradicting our assumption that it's dimension one. So the projection on to one coordinate axis or the other must be dimension one, and WLOG we can choose the axis to be the $x_1$ axis.

The reason that a nonzero polynomial in $x_1$ does not vanish on this image is that every nonzero nonconstant polynomials in $x_1$ cuts out a codimension 1 (aka dimension zero) subvariety of $\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb F_q}$. As a subset of a set has the same or smaller dimension, this means that the projection can't be contained in the zero locus of any nonconstant polynomial in $x_1$.